# nginx rule for NOT ignoring request parameters

Tags: regex, redirect, configuration, nginx

Ok, I just want to add parameters whenever `/search` is called:

```
rewrite ^/search$ /search?foo=bar redirect;
```

Seems simple logic but it leads to endless loop because nginx takes the parameters separately and so the `$` isn't working anymore. `/search?foo=bar` trigger it again and again and again because it stupidly matches.

So is there any working solution without touching the `$args`?

(I want to use regex because the matching rule is a bit more complicate but basically its what I want)

Answer (score 4):

According to [the nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite), "rewrite operates only on path, not parameters."

So maybe the key is to rewrite only if the parameter is not found.

```
    if ($args !~ "(^|&)foo=") {
        rewrite ^/search$ /search?foo=bar redirect;
    }
```

Comment: I was just about to submit the same response. I agree.

Comment: Is there a danger in overwriting (or doublewriting) the query string, though?  Perhaps the replacement should actually be ``/search?foo=bar&$args``--give it a shot and let us know @Calmon!